# How to replace a node in MarkLogic?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I need to replace the existing node with the new name using MarkLogic of an XML sheet.

I don't use Query Console and I write all my code in .sjs file. When I have gone through the steps given in MarkLogic docs, it is throwing some errors.

Sample code:

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I have to change tag "from" and replace it as "sender", ie. expected output:

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <sender>Jani</sender>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Java Code:

**uploading sjs transform from java**

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(IP, 8000,
                           DATABASE_NAME, USERNAME, PWD, Authentication.DIGEST);

// get transform mgr
TransformExtensionsManager transMgr = client.newServerConfigManager()
    .newTransformExtensionsManager();
FileInputStream transStream = null;

try {
    transStream = new FileInputStream(path);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
InputStreamHandle ipStreamHandle = new InputStreamHandle(transStream);
transMgr.writeJavascriptTransform(JS_TRANSFORM_NAME, ipStreamHandle);
client.release();
```

**Applying the transform before reading the data from MarkLogic. The actual data in database won't be updated**

```
ServerTransform transform = new ServerTransform(transformName);
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(IP, 8000,
    DATABASE_NAME, USERNAME, PWD, Authentication.DIGEST);
JSONDocumentManager docMgr = clientNew.newJSONDocumentManager();
InputStreamHandle handle = new InputStreamHandle();
docMgr.read("/" + uri + JSON_EXT, handle, transform);
String document = handle.toString();
clientNew.release();
return document;
```

.sjs code:

```
declareUpdate();
var n = new NodeBuilder();
node = n.addElement("sender", "Jani").toNode();

xdmp.nodeReplace(
  cts.doc("/example.xml").xpath("/note/from"),
  node
);
```

Error:

```
Operation not allowed on the currently executing transaction with identifier declareUpdate
```

Comment: Please post _what_ you tried, and how it fails (exact error message, wrong output, ...).

Comment: This is one I tried:

xdmp:document-insert("/example.xml",
    <note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>);

xdmp:nodeReplace(doc("/example.xml")/note/from, <sender>Jack</sender>);

Comment: ERROR:
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: config/transforms write failed: Internal Server Error. Server Message: JS-JAVASCRIPT: <note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't -- Error running JavaScript request: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.

Comment: Better edit those into your original question, code and messages are barely readable in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let me note that you can use JavaScript in Query Console (just change the query type). I assume you need to put your code into a file so that it will be part of your application, but running in Query Console is a good way to figure out what code you need.

That said, the code you provided in the comment is a mix of XQuery and JavaScript. xdmp:document-insert() is XQuery -- you can tell by the case, JavaScript doesn't support identifiers with hyphens. The xdmp:nodeReplace should be either xdmp:node-replace (XQuery) or xdmp.nodeReplace (JavaScript).

The problem you've run into is that XML is not valid content in a JavaScript file -- the < and > symbols are interpreted as less than and greater than. You can accomplish what you're trying to do with code like this:

```
declareUpdate();

var n = new NodeBuilder();
node = n.addElement("sender", "Jani").toNode();

xdmp.nodeReplace(
  cts.doc("/example.xml").xpath("/note/from"),
  node
);
```

Before going much further, I think you would benefit from reading the [Server-side JavaScript introduction](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/javascript). That will give you a better foundation for what you're trying to accomplish.

---

Edit: 
In light of additional information from the comments, the solution is that the JavaScript code you're using is intended to update the database, while you want to do a read transformation in memory ([Guidelines for Writing Transforms](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_83781)). Based on [Writing JavaScript Transformations](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_77476), here's what you want instead:

```
function fromToSender(context, params, content) 
{
  var doc = content.toObject();
  delete doc.note.from;
  doc.sender = 'Jani';
  return doc;
};

exports.transform = fromToSender;
```

Note that this is a library module with a transform called "fromToSender". Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks Dave.

I have got this Error when performing the above code:

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: read failed: Internal Server Error. Server Message: declareUpdate(); -- Operation not allowed on the currently executing transaction with identifier declareUpdate . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.

Comment: The code above will work in Query Console and ought to work in a main module (as opposed to a library module). I don't know the context in which you're trying to run it, so I can't say specifically why you're seeing that, but the general answer is that MarkLogic thinks you're doing a query when you want to be doing an update. The difference is described here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_40746

Comment: I have been working on .java file in eclipse and has written all the above code in the .sjs and linked to the .java file. Then I'm going to connect it to a server.
Here I'm not yet all using the query console.

Comment: Is your .sjs a REST API Service extension? (Assuming you're using the Java Client API, here's [Creating a Resource Extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_49302).) If so, you might be trying to do an update in a GET, which runs as a read-only query by default.

Comment: I'm not using REST API but using Server side java script for the xml transformation. I'm linking my .sjs file from java eclipse and is throwing an error on the declareUpdate(). ERROR:  "Operation not allowed on the currently executing transaction with identifier declareUpdate ".

Comment: Please edit your original question to show the Java code you're using to call the .sjs file. Showing a minimal version of the .sjs that causes the error would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. I have updated the question. Could you please review and suggest the changes to be done for avoiding of the errors.

Comment: The Java code you posted loads the .sjs into memory, but does not call it. That said, I think I see the problem. [Transforms are intended for some specific purposes](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transforms#id_48130). I'm not clear whether you intend to accomplish one of those, or if you're trying to change the content of your database. If the latter, you'll want a tool like [Corb](http://marklogic.github.io/corb/).

Comment: I have edited the code above. We are uploading the sjs transform from java and also trying to apply the transform to an xml which is saved in marklogic after readind it. We are not trying to change the content in the database. We are trying to implement a read transform.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect where we ended up. I think that should do it for you.